# Prolog, using expressions

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn SWI prolog,
but my simple program fails when I believe it should succeed.

```
%My code:
orthogonal((X1,Y1,Z1),(X2,Y2,Z2)) :- (X1*X2)+(Y1*Y2)+(Z1*Z2)==0.
integerVector((X,Y,Z)) :- integer(X),integer(Y),integer(Z).

?-orthogonal((1,0,0),(0,0,1)).
```

I press compile Buffer in the pseudoemacs window and the output is:

```
% [PATH].pl compiled 0.00 sec, 136 bytes
ERROR: emacs_prolog_mode ->error_at_location: Argument 1 (int): `int' expected, found `@11470948?start'
ERROR: emacs_prolog_mode ->error_at_location: Argument 1 (int): `int' expected, found `@11470948?start'
Warning: [PATH]s.pl:5:
        Goal (directive) failed: user:orthogonal((1,0,0), (0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used `(==)/2` in place of `(=:=)/2` which evaluates its arguments as arithmetic expressions.

You can use `(X,Y,Z)`, but it isn't a triple as in e.g. Haskell. To see this:

```
?- write_canonical((1,2,3)).
','(1,','(2,3))

?- (1,2,3) = (X,Y).
   X = 1, Y = (2,3).
```

Comment: What should I use in the place of triples?

Comment: @Oxinabox: either use lists, or a functor `v/3` if all your vectors are 3d.

Answer (score 6):

Expressions in Prolog simply represent syntactic term trees.  To evaluate an expression you need to `X is Y` which evaluates Y as an arithmetic expression and unifies the result with X.  Alternatively you can use `X =:= Y` which evaluates both X and Y as arithmetic expressions, then unifies the results.

Cheers!